# PowerShell with Square Brackets

Tags: powershell

So, I've read a lot about the Square Bracket [] problems with renaming a file with Powershell.  Most of these post talked about removing the brackets.  I have a need to keep the brackets, and just remove the file extension `.crypted(CryptoLocker)`. There are 400,000+ files and 172,000+ folders.  I tried the Move-Item cmdlet...

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp *.crypted | Move-Item -LiteralPath {$_.FullName.Replace(".crypted", "")}
```

I get an error `Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'C:\temp\Rule [1].txt' does not exist`

As you might be able to see the new path is correct, but it says it doesn't exist.  I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried the `rename-item` cmdlet?

Comment: @jisaak The `rename-item` cmdlet fails because of the brackets and a lack of a `-LiteralPath`.  That was the original need to switch to `-Move-Item`.  The [] are wildcards inside of powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Debugging tip:* when you have issues with code and you are using the pipeline, rewrite the code to not use the pipeline and break the problem down into steps and insert debugging aids to help troubleshoot. Could be Write-Host, saving to temp variables, etc.

For me, your Move-Item as written does not work, and I get a similar error message.

**Here is what I arrived at as a solution:**

```
Get-ChildItem *.crypted | ForEach-Object {Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace('.crypted', '')}
```

*Note that I pass 2 arguments to `Move-Item` after `-LiteralPath`, and there are no backticks needed or anything out of the ordinary.*

**Here is my work to demonstrate the issue, and my solution.**

```
D:\test\move> dir


    Directory: D:\test\move


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        3/17/2016   9:21 PM         100347 file [1].pdf


D:\test\move> Get-ChildItem *.pdf | Move-Item -LiteralPath {$_.FullName.Replace('1', '2')}
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'D:\test\move\file [2].pdf' does not exist.
At line:1 char:23
+ ... ldItem *.pdf | Move-Item -LiteralPath {$_.FullName.Replace('1', '2')}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

D:\test\move> Get-ChildItem *.pdf | ForEach-Object {Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace('1', '2')}
D:\test\move> dir


    Directory: D:\test\move


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        3/17/2016   9:21 PM         100347 file [2].pdf
```

Works on the extention too...

```
D:\test\move> dir


    Directory: D:\test\move


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        3/17/2016   9:21 PM         100347 file [2].txt.crypted


D:\test\move> Get-ChildItem *.crypted | ForEach-Object {Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace('.crypted', '')}
D:\test\move> dir


    Directory: D:\test\move


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        3/17/2016   9:21 PM         100347 file [2].txt


D:\test\move>
```

Comment: This was the solution.  I tired to use the `ForEach-Object` but I missed something there too.  I appreciate the help and extra direction.  This was a thoroughly tested answer and I had no problems making it work in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

In order to work around the brackets, escape it with double backtick ``` `` ``` like so,

```
gci c:\temp\brackets *.crypted | % { 
  move-item $_.FullName.replace('[','``[') $_.FullName.Replace(".crypted", "")
}
```

Doubling the backtick is needed so that a backtick is passed and not interpreted as escape character to the bracket. This is a bit messy, so it looks like a bug in Powershell or very surprising a behavior.

Comment: If you use `-LiteralPath` you do not need to use backticks, and you can avoid writing *messy* code.  I also show why the OPs original command gave an error.

Comment: @vonPryz  This solution works too.  Thank you for your help as well. While the `-LiteralPath` option is a cleaner way to go I can also see a use this in the future and greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: I've never heard of that.  `get-childitem '``[there]'`.  What's actually going on and where is it documented?  Powershell is like an english muffin, with many nooks and crannies.

Comment: @js2010 Since the answer's about 7 years old, I don't recall whch version of Powershell I worked back then. I'd hazard a guess it was about when Powershell interprets square brackets as literal brackets and when they are regex char ranges.